# Hashing values with salt in sql snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table A in snowflake database with a numerique column values, i want to anonymise this values in order to extract with a simple select query in csv file.

i tried with hash function but the problem that i can not get the hash key to send it with the csv file.

```
select id,value,hash(value) as hashed_value from A;

id|value|hashed_value|
1 |1254 |542557895421|
2 |5022 |999854215470|
3 |3327 |102554899873|
```

as i said before, i should have a key (salt) to use it in the hashing.

have you any idea please ? i will be grateful.

Comment: Hello, could you please show us the query you tried, and what is the expected output?

Comment: Hello, i edited the post, what i want is to have a key (salt) in order to hash and to send it with the csv export.

Comment: Can you explain further what the overall objective is? Are you wanting to be able to subsequently decrypt the values in the csv file? If not, why do you want to include a salt value with the file?

Comment: @NickW the goal is to be able to decrypt the values later by another team this is why we (me and the other team) to be ok on a salt

Comment: If you want to be able to encrypt data fields in Snowflake and then decrypt it once it has been exported out to a file then you probably need to use your own encryption service, accessed using an external function from Snowflake and some other mechanism for your csv file. You might be able to use the ENCRYPT_RAW function and build your own external decryption process. The docs specifically state that ENCRYPT won’t work for your use case and to use ENCRYPT_RAW - but doesn’t explain how this could be implemented

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your request is that you want to anonymize the values. The inclusion of a salt implies that you want output such that repeated numeric values have different anonymized values. One simple way you could do this is to generate a UUID and concatenate it with the numeric value before hashing. In the example below, note that ID 3 and ID 4 have the same value (3327) but different hash values:

```
with A(id,value) as (
select * from values
(1,1254),
(2,5022),
(3,3327),
(4,3327)
)
select id,value,hash(uuid_string()||value) as hashed_value from A;
```

| ID | VALUE | HASHED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1254 | -1121100471006795828 |
| 2 | 5022 | -6457111439169190593 |
| 3 | 3327 | -7553953675807280613 |
| 4 | 3327 | 671032278892242065 |

Comment: Thanks @Dave, but i suppose to have the same hash values for the same column values and also a salt or a key to send it in order to decrypt the values later